# Rails - display a default image if record does not have an uploaded image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a site where I want to be able to display a default image for a user profile if they have not yet uploaded their own image.

I can place the default image in the asset/images directory, but I am wondering how I should make the logic work with image_tag to be able to display the user's image in the view if they've uploaded one or display the default placeholder image in the view if the user has not uploaded one.

I am new to rails, but I would guess that I should put the logic somewhere in my user model and conditionally set the image attribute for the user? I am using Paperclip as well.

Comment: Just use the || operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paperclip gem supports a `default_url` option that is a path to an image that will be rendered if the user has no image. From the paperclip README:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
end
```

So if you call `user.avatar.url(:thumb)` and it is missing, paperclip will try to render `/images/thumb/missing.png`. If you create your default missing images and line them up with the `default_url` parameter, you should be able to let paperclip handle the rest.

Comment: Definitely better solution